# Jittery login buttons

Tags: bug, user-interface, login

When I go to the log in screen for a StackExchange site, I am presented with a few buttons. However, there is a small area for each button (usually not more than 1-2 pixels) that causes the cursor to intersect with the button's hit box and moves it a small distance to the side. This moves the hit box to the side as well, and causes the cursor to no longer intersect with it, resetting it to its original position; the cursor again intersects, and the result is a constantly jittering button.

I know this is a minor issue, but seems a bit unprofessional. I would recommend that the buttons' hit boxes remain stationary, even if the button moves, preventing the buttons from jittering.
[image: Buggy login buttons]